# Fix microphone volume for a user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, alsa, pulseaudio

I need to fix the microphone volume for any user in Ubuntu 16. What I want is to fix the volume, say, to %40, and keep it at that value for all times. It must be changed by no user except root. How can I do such a config? And with what tool?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All mixer controls of a card are managed with a single device node (`/dev/snd/controlCx`), so it is not possible to use file permissions for this.

However, you could program a separate tool that calls
`snd_ctl_elem_lock()` for the mixer control that no other program should
be able to change.